# Generate pdf for given url at server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, angular10

I am looking to generate pdf document for the given url. The client will send ids and using that ids server will create a url and use pdf generator to produce pdf. The pdf is generated but for the login page and not the desired page.

Client is angular 10, server is .net core 3.1
The authentication cookies are assigned to the pdf coverter but still no luck.

code

```
private FileContentResult PdfGenerate(int bookId, int? pageId)
{
//generate pdf for this url. This url can be accessed in the browser
string url = $"{ConfigHelper.AngularServer}/portal/{bookId}/{pageId}";
}
```

Currently I have tried with SelectPdf and Synfusion but login page is converted to pdf and not the page in the url.

Comment: What happens when you browse `$"{ConfigHelper.AngularServer}/portal/{bookId}/{pageId}"` URL directly in the browser?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the web page with bookid and pageid is rendered

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you access the page specified, you are automatically forwarded to the login page, because you are not authorized. What you need it so get authentication token (authenticate yourself before hand) and then send the actual request with token added to the cookies/headers (whatever system is used for login).

For human-reading of page via browser, browser does this action for you automatically. You go to login page, you authenticate (enter login/password, press confirm), server confirms you are authorized and provides you some token details. This token is then added to each of your request towards the webserver.

---

Additional info: There is example how it works with some code https://fullstackmark.com/post/21/user-authentication-and-identity-with-angular-aspnet-core-and-identityserver .

However there are many articles over the internet and this topic is too broad to have fully qualified answer. We need to know what authorization is used, what is the login address & what requirements are for the authorization, etc.

Comment: I am assigning the authentication cookies as mentioned in the question. For instance foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies)
            {
                converter.Options.HttpCookies.Add(cookie.Key, cookie.Value);
            } When I check authentication it suceeds but looks like when it reaches the login page it fails.